# Yii: validation rule skipped on update

Tags: php, yii

I have a model and when I use the `create` method, the validation works.

When I use the `update` method, the validation is skipped.

This is the validation rule:

```
array('url', 'url'),
```

Do I have to set the `on` param for the scenarios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no use it not required you can use in a manner

```
if($model->validate())
$model->save();
```

This will validate your model before save

Comment: Answer is wrong. If you are using `$model->save()` you don't need call validate manualy. As you can read here, http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#save-detail `$model->validate()` is called on "save()" every time. This is where you need to call it manualy: `$model->validate() ? $model->update() : null;`

Answer (score 0):

```
 if($model->save())
```

Use if then only it validate itz own page
else it will validate but redirect on next page we cant see the validation